# Is the null-coalescing operator a good thing?

Tags: php, null-coalescing-operator

I personally find myself using it a lot of times just to prevent, for example, "Undefined index" exceptions when trying to access arrays.

In addition, I find myself then using this to check if an array contains that key. You'll find an example in the following:

```
function getValue($key)
{
    return $this->array[$key] ?? null;
}

// ---

if (!$object->get('key'))
    // Do something when the array doesn't contain that key or the value is empty.
```

---

When is it OK to use the null-coalescing operator and when not? Is it OK to use it like this or is it recommended to do things like that in another way?

Comment: Your use case can't distinguish between the key not existing and its value being *falsey*…

Answer (score 1):

The [PHP Manual for the NULL COALESCING OPERATOR](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) lists a similar example:

```
<?php
// Fetches the value of $_GET['user'] and returns 'nobody'
// if it does not exist.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? 'nobody';
// This is equivalent to:
$username = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : 'nobody';

// Coalescing can be chained: this will return the first
// defined value out of $_GET['user'], $_POST['user'], and
// 'nobody'.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? $_POST['user'] ?? 'nobody';
?>
```

So I assume it is safe to use it this way.

> When is it OK to use the null-coalescing operator and when not?

It is OK to use it when you do not need to distinguish between a NULL value and a UNDEFINED value, and you can treat them the same, as if they were both NULL.